# How to split a string into multiple columns?

Tags: r, string, dplyr, split, tidyverse

I have a string that looks like this:

```
# character string
string <- "lambs:    cows: 281        chickens: 20   goats: 3     trees: 13"
```

I want to create a dataframe that looks like this:

```
# structure
lambs <- NA
cows <- 281
chickens <- 20
goats <- 3
trees <- 13

# dataframe
df <- 
  cbind(lambs, cows, chickens, goats, trees)  %>% 
  as.data.frame()
```

This is what I have tried so far:

```
# split string
test <- strsplit(string, " ")
test
```

The data is quite unclean so the spacing isn't always consistent, and sometimes there are lambs and sometimes there are no lambs (as in: `"lamb: 5   cow: 50"` and `"lamb:    cow: 40"`. What is the easiest way to do this using tidyverse?

Comment: Is it a fixed width file by chance? How did the data get so messy in the first place? You would need to make some strong assumptions about the data in order to import it. But with only one example line it's hard to tell what might be going on.

Comment: another one: `read.table(text = gsub('\\b(?=[A-z])', '\n', string, perl = TRUE), sep = ':')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `str_match_all` and pass the pattern to extract.

```
tmp <- stringr::str_match_all(string, '\\s*(.*?):\\s*(\\d+)?')[[1]][, -1]
data <- type.convert(data.frame(tmp), as.is = TRUE)

#        X1  X2
#1    lambs  NA
#2     cows 281
#3 chickens  20
#4    goats   3
#5    trees  13
```

This divides data into two columns where the first column is everything before colon (`:`) except whitespace and the second column is number followed after it. I have made the number part as optional so as to accommodate cases like `'lambs'` which do not have number.

Comment: Excellent approach as always.  You can easily convert all solutions here in a fantastic book. Thanks for sharing

Comment: Thanks! I just tried it with the real data but forgot to mention that some of the numbers have commas (5,000 or 13,14,00) ect. Is there a way to address this? I noticed the code cut it off to the first digit before the comma.

Comment: I think a simple fix without changing much of the code would be to remove the comma using `gsub` i.e `stringr::str_match_all(gsub(',', '', string), '\\s*(.*?):\\s*(\\d+)?')[[1]][, -1]`

Comment: Amazing, thank you so much! Also just noticed some of the numbers have a space, like "5, 23,336" Would you happen to know a simple fix for that too? (nvm, figured this out by making a list and unlisting in the pattern argument)

Comment: agree with #AnilGoyal - really neat approach / should write a book! @RonakShah, you should be focusing on the cricket though :D

Comment: @RonakShah, the '?' inside the regex is to make it not greedy?

Comment: @KarthikS Yes, that is correct since we have multiple occurrence of the same pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```r
gre <- gregexpr("\\b([A-Za-z]+:\\s*[0-9]*)\\b", string)
regmatches(string, gre)
# [[1]]
# [1] "lambs:    "   "cows: 281"    "chickens: 20" "goats: 3"     "trees: 13"   
lapply(regmatches(string, gre), strcapture, pattern = "(.*):(.*)", proto = list(anim = character(0), n = character(0)))
# [[1]]
#       anim    n
# 1    lambs     
# 2     cows  281
# 3 chickens   20
# 4    goats    3
# 5    trees   13
frames <- lapply(regmatches(string, gre), strcapture,
                 pattern = "(.*):(.*)", proto = list(anim = character(0), n = character(0)))
```

If you have multiple strings (and not just one), then this ensure that each string is processed and then all data is combined.

```r
alldat <- do.call(rbind, frames)
alldat$n <- as.integer(alldat$n)
alldat
#       anim   n
# 1    lambs  NA
# 2     cows 281
# 3 chickens  20
# 4    goats   3
# 5    trees  13
```

If you instead really need the data in a "wide" format, then

```r
do.call(rbind, lapply(frames, function(z) do.call(data.frame, setNames(as.list(as.integer(z$n)), z$anim))))
#   lambs cows chickens goats trees
# 1    NA  281       20     3    13
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `read.table`. The "no lambs" issue can be solved by putting in a zero with `gsub`.

```
r <- na.omit(unlist(read.table(text=gsub(": ", " 0", string), sep=" ")))
r <- replace(r, r == 0, NA)

## long format
type.convert(as.data.frame(matrix(r, ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)), as.is=TRUE)
#         V1  V2
# 1    lambs  NA
# 2     cows 281
# 3 chickens  20
# 4    goats   3
# 5    trees  13

## wide format
setNames(type.convert(r[seq(r) %% 2 == 0]), r[seq(r) %% 2 == 1])
# lambs     cows chickens    goats    trees 
#    NA      281       20        3       13
```